# Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v4.8.2. Update it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby

I have a Rails app running Rails 5.2.1 and Ruby 2.5.1. When I run the Rails server, I get the following error:

```
Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v4.8.2. Update it.
```

When I go to the console to check the version of Node I have installed, with `node -v` I get:

```
v10.11.0
```

When I type `nvm ls`, I get:

```
default -> node (-> v10.11.0)
node -> stable (-> v10.11.0) (default)
stable -> 10.11 (-> v10.11.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.14.4 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.12.0 (-> N/A)
```

I've looked at other answers on Stackoverflow, and most make mention of therubyracer gem, but I don't have that gem installed for this app. Where can this version of Node be hiding and how can I delete it?

Comment: how have you installed ruby? are you using RVM?  did you try https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails ?

Comment: run your rails console and past the output of these:
`ENV['NVM_PATH']
ENV['NVM_BIN']
ENV['PATH']`

Comment: `ENV['NVM_PATH'] and ENV['NVM_BIN']` both give me nil. `ENV['PATH'] gives me /.rvm/rubies
/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: It's likely your environment `$PATH` is not correct in terminal configuration.  Please paste in your answer the output of `gem env` also what shell are you using?  bash? zsh ?

Answer (score 19):

You need to update the version of Node.js installed.

This issue was addressed here: https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/144

If you have Node.js installed by [NPM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and your operating system package manager (such as `apt`, `dnf`, `yum`, or `pacman`), then remove the version installed by the OS package manager.

```
# Using apt on Debian or Ubuntu based Linux distributions
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

If you are using a recent version of Debian or Ubuntu you can install Node.js like so

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

If using a [Ruby Docker container](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/226) add the following before installing the nodejs package. Notice that we are not using `sudo` in the container.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
```

More information on installing and updating Node.js can be found here:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager

Comment: I experienced the same problem on Gitlab within our CI pipeline and using a ruby `2.5.3` container. Adding `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -` fixed the problem.

Comment: I have a docker container and it's still installing the same v4.8.2. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava Try a newer version from here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Harlem Already tried with setup_16.x

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava Make sure to remove any previous versions of node before installing new versions

Comment: @Harlem In container there's only nodejs version 4.8.2, which I deleted